# How to know whether .pem file is correct or not

Tags: php, iphone, push-notification, pem

I have created a .pem file to be used for Production push notification,

and uploaded in server.

But when sending push notification, it is giving error like this.

$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx); not working, return failed.

what is this error, how to solve it.

Finally, how to know whether the .pem file is correct or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use "certtool" from the GnuTLS binaries to validate the certificate (`certtool -i --infile cert.pem`). Windows binaries are also [available](http://josefsson.org/gnutls4win/).

I don't have an answer for your `stream_socket_client` problem. Make sure the context is initialized correctly, an example is shown in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.stream-socket-client.php#77497).